# Error gcc - undefined reference to symbol '__getauxval@@GLIBC_2.17'

Tags: c, gcc

### Hello everyone.

I am trying to compile simple C code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

But I get this error.

```sh
$ gcc main.c
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/libgcc.a(lse-init.o): undefined reference to symbol '__getauxval@@GLIBC_2.17'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line                                       
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that the error occurs due to the fact that the compidator cannot find the font, but this is not accurate. And the same error occurs in **C++**.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What version of `gcc` are you using and on what platform? Probably not related to this issue, but `void main()` isn't a valid signature. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: Currently version 10.2.0 is installed and it is installed on termux with proot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, this error occurs due to the fact that libraries of type libc were not in the common directory.
These libraries:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 10504 10504 1827624 Aug  4 16:27 /lib/conlib/libc-2.32.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 10504 10504 4592750 Aug  4 16:27 /lib/conlib/libc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 10504 10504     351 Aug  4 16:27 /lib/conlib/libc.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10504 10504      18 Aug  4 16:27 /lib/conlib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.32.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 10504 10504   24964 Aug  4 16:27 /lib/conlib/libc_nonshared.a
```